# How prove this $f(x)=g(x)=h(x)=0$?

Tags: polynomials

let polynomial $f(x),g(x),h(x)\in C[x]$, and such
$$f^2(x)=xg^2(x)+xh^2(x),$$

> prove or disprove 
>   $$f(x)=g(x)=h(x)=0$$

I know solve this follow problem 
 let polynomial $f(x),g(x),h(x)\in R[x]$, and such
$$f^2(x)=xg^2(x)+xh^2(x),$$

prove or disprove 
$$f(x)=g(x)=h(x)=0$$

then I guess when $f,g,h\in C[x]$ is true? Thank you

Comment: What if $g(x) = 1$, $h(x)=i$ and $f(x)=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this won't be true at all in $\Bbb C$. It might even be the case that each one of $f,g,h$ is non zero. There follows an example:
$$
f(x) = 2e^{i\pi/4}x,\qquad g(x) = ix+1, \qquad h(x) = x+i. 
$$

Answer (score 0):

We can, without loss of generality, assume one of $g$ and $h$ is nonzero.

Let $g(x)=x^a g_1(x)$, $h(x)=x^a h_1(x)$ in such a way that either $x$ doesn't divide $g_1$ or doesn't divide $h_1$.

Then $x$ doesn't divide $g_1(x)^2+h_1(x)^2$ (unless …). But
$$
f(x)^2=x^{2a+1}(g_1(x)^2+h_1(x)^2)
$$
so …

Comment: You made a mistake with *"then $x$ doesn't divide $g_1(x)^2+h_1(x)^2$"*. See my comment on the OP.

Comment: @Siméon I was silently assuming that $g$ and $h$ are non zero.

Comment: Still, take $g(x) = 1$ and $h(x) = i$ for instance.

Comment: @Siméon What's the problem in that case? We'd simply have $a=0$.

Comment: The problem is that $x$ does divide $g_1(x)^2+h_1(x)^2$.

Comment: @Siméon OK, I'll edit.